# r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}" - invalid syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

I have this line generating a syntax error when I run `python3 ./twitter_filtered_stream.py`

`r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"`

All of the relevant code looks like this:

```
# To set your enviornment variables in your terminal run the following line:
# export 'BEARER_TOKEN'='<your_bearer_token>'
bearer_token = os.environ.get("BEARER_TOKEN")


def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2FilteredStreamPython"
    return r
```

I get:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

when trying to run the code.

I setup the variable in the terminal with the `export` line, and when I go to the terminal and type `echo $BEARER_TOKEN` the correct value shows. Must be something simple I'm overlooking, I'm a little rusty - haven't programmed in python in a while...

Answer (score 0):

I am using a version of python 3 (3.5) which doesn't support the `f"` format. I would need to use python 3.6.